# How can I add color in Charts.newTableChart for google script?

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I add color in Charts.newTableChart for google scrip?

```
function doGet() {

    var app = UiApp.createApplication();

    var data = Charts.newDataTable()

    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Name")

    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Gender")

    .addRow(["Michael", "Male", 12, 5])

    .addRow(["Michael", "Male", 12, 5])

    .build();
    var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart().setDataTable(data).build();

    app.add(tableChart);

    return app;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Add color on your ChartTable

for example  :

```
    builder.setOption('title', 'Earnings projections');
 builder.setOption('animation.duration', 1000);
 builder.setOption('legend', {position: 'top', textStyle: {color: 'blue', fontSize: 16}});
```

You have a doc :
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-table-chart-builder#setOption(String,Object)

If you use a Grid you can use a label 
for example :

```
gridInfo.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel("info  ").setStyleAttribute('font-weight','bold')); 
gridLink.setWidget(0, 3, app.createLabel(" * link ").setStyleAttributes({background: "#BBD4E9", color: "red"}));
```

Doc : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/ui_supportedStyles

It's an example for you

I hope this help can help you.

Comment: I try to do a semaphore for my dashboard. I need to add color red, blue, yellow to my table. Can your sentence help me?

Comment: I found a new way to show my semaphore with grid... var semaforo=uiApp.createGrid(5, 4) ... any doubt tell me.

Comment: If you use a grid , you can use CSS,  I update my post